# Knockout js hide button if value is greater than

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am defining a variable after the page load (storing numerical json data)

I can successfully put this variable in:

```
<span data-bind="text: extQty"></span>
```

And when the variable changes it updates the span with the appropriate variable (That works fine).

But it doesn't update my variable within my enable:

```
<p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add, enable: pagedList().length < extQty" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Extension</a></p>
```

I need to have the enable effectively disable based on the value that is presented to "extQty". Right now I'm sending 5 to the extQty, and it seems the variable is only updating inside the "text" data-bind rather than the "enable" data-bind.

Comment: @generalhenry that is not the same question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout enable binding **do not work with anchor tags**.

So you have 2 solution to this.

**Solution 1**

```
<a href='#' title="edit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind='click: function() { 
 if(pagedList().length < extQty())
 {
    //call the desired method from here
 }' >
```

**Solution 2**

This button displays only when your condition is success and it has click binding

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add, visible: pagedList().length < extQty()" href="#" title="edit">
```

This button displays only when your negative condition is success and it do not have click binding

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="visible: pagedList().length >= extQty()" href="#" title="edit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<p class="pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="style: { display: (pagedList().length < extQty) ? 'block' : 'none' }" 
        href="#" title="edit">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Extension
    </a>
</p>
```

Or else as pointed by @NaveenKumar.. You can use visible attribute...